# Which traits should I look for when purcashing plugs for self-assembled power cables?

Tags: cables, cable-assemblies

For example, here is a picture of two schuko female plugs I got (I marked the types with numbers), the materials at the connections are different too:

[image]

So which one is better and why if that matters? Is there any specific trait that I should look for in the future if I want to get high quality plugs and start assembling power cables with them?

Comment: The contacts of *2* are Nickel-plated. That works against corrosion, but that should be only an issue in the wet – for which these sockets are not made for. The wire socket with the square nut *1* has is more reliable.

Comment: You should use a ferrule on the ground wire for both plugs.

Comment: I would use a ferule on all of them, I assume there is no problem with any type of these types supporting ferrules?

Comment: It also depends on the cable used. Obviously, using too large a cable with too small an entry hole/clamp is an issue, but too large a unit with a small cable is an issue too since it  leaves a lot of room round the cable entry with poor clamping characteristics.